# Create Queue/Topic in Wildfly 10 using ActiveMQ and console

Tags: queue, jms, wildfly

Does anyone know how I can add a destination via the Wildfly 10 Console?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You have to press destinations in the drop down menu.